# php imagejpeg quality stinks: why?

Tags: php, image-processing, antialiasing

im taking image uploads on a website and changing the images to thumbnails that fit onto a 100 x 100 white square.  the problem is that the images look like they dont anti-alias properly.  images sized down in photoshop look smooth, but these look crunchy, like super sharpened.

take a look at [these samples](http://www.nonwhite.com/php_image_resize.jpg), showing full size on the left and thumbnails on the right (view at 100%).  the photo comes out looking ridiculously sharpened, but a lot of people might not be bothered by it.  the drawing though is waaay unacceptable.  those curved lines just dont anti-alias at all and become dotted lines.

im using imagejpg(), and the jpg quality i choose has no effect on the crunchiness. heres some of the code surrounding it:

```
$tmp_img = imagecreatetruecolor( $maxSize, $maxSize );
$white = ImageColorAllocate ($tmp_img, 255, 255, 255);
ImageFill($tmp_img, 0, 0, $white);
imagecopyresized( $tmp_img, $img, $offsetx, $offsety, 0, 0, $new_width, $new_height, $width, $height );
$thumbFullPath = "{$pathToThumbs}/{$filenameNoExtension}.jpg";
imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $thumbFullPath, 90 );
```

any ideas? is this normal? thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You may want to try [`imagecopyresampled`](http://php.net/imagecopyresampled) instead of `imagecopyresized`. It's slower but uses a more sophisticated algorithm for determining the colour of every pixel in the new image.

Answer (score 6):

change the last line to:

`imagejpeg( $tmp_img, $thumbFullPath, 100 );`

see: http://us4.php.net/manual/en/function.imagejpeg.php

Also, try using `imagecopyresampled()` rather than `imagecopyresized()`

see: http://us4.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecopyresampled.php

Comment: There won't be much of a difference between 90 and 100. Besides, I think it's more the scaling operation than the save operation that wastes the result. Also, OP said changing the quality doesn't enhance anything.

Comment: right, but it may help...10%... `imagecopyresampled()` has worked wonders for me in the past.

Comment: agree, "try using imagecopyresampled() rather than imagecopyresized()"

Comment: @OP If it's not solved by this, please show some example images.

Comment: i will give that a try a bit later, when ive patted down the current set of flames burning my desk.  THANKS SO MUCH - imagecopyresampled() sounds promising!

Comment: i couldnt resist trying it real quick, AND IT WORKS!  you guys roooooocckckkk.  kinda makes me wonder why anyone would use imagecopyresized, or why it even exists.  thanks!

Comment: imagecopyresized probably use simple nearest neighbor sampling that gives low quality. More precise scaling algorithms like imagecopyresampled apply low pass filters (blur) before sub-sampling this makes hi frequency spikes disappear in tumbnail.

Comment: Actually, imagejpeg() seems to only write 72ppi images, even if you load a 300ppi image, add some text, and save it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$imagepath = /path/to/image.jpg; 
$image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imagepath); 
header('Content-Type: image/jpeg'); 
imagejpeg($image, NULL, 100);
```

Last line is so important!